# Python - How to scrape a class one by one

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying to scrape a value one by one, meaning that I used a for loop to scrape a selected class and then try to print out item by item. The HTML is looking:

[image: HTML]

What I tried to do is following code:

```
select_tags = bs4.find_all('select', {'autocomplete': 'off'})
    test = []
    for select_tag in select_tags:

        if select_tag.select("option.disabled.ReminderRevealButton"):
            continue
        else:
            print(select_tag)
            test.append(select_tag.text)
```

Output that I am getting is:

```
['\nPlease select number\n\n                            (Number 1)                        \n\n                            (Number 2)                        \n\n                            (Number 3)                        \n\n                            (Number 4)                        \n\n                            (Number 5)                        \n\n                            (Number 6)                        \n\n                            (Number 7)                        \n\n                            (Number 7)                        \n\n                            (Number 8)                        \n\n                            (Number 9)                        \n\n                            (Number 10)                        \n\n                            (Number 11)                        \n']}
```

which indeed prints out the names. However the problem is that it prints it all out as one line and not (the numbers from HTML code) one by one.

What do I need to do to be able to solve so it prints Number 1,2,3,4,5.. one by one?

Comment: you actually want `select > option:not(.disabled.ReminderRevealButton)`

Comment: Woops! That was a mistake that I also didn't noticed! Thanks @hjpotter92 - But what do you suggest me to change in that if I might ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it print one in line because you're looping the `select` tag and not `option` tag. The `:not` is not supported by BeautifulSoup.

```
select_tags = bs4.find_all('select', {'autocomplete': 'off'})
test = []

for select_tag in select_tags:
    for option in select_tag.select('option'):
    # if set(['ReminderRevealButton', 'disabled']) == set(option.get('class')):
    if "disabled ReminderRevealButton" in str(option):
        # print(str)
        # <option class="disabled ReminderRevealButton"> (Number 1) </option>
        continue
    else:
        print(option.get('class'))
        test.append(option.text.strip())
```

I'm not using `option['class']` or `option.get('class')` because it return array of class, if the class has same length you can use `set()` to compare else need loop.